# jsonp multi callback calling error

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsonp

i have a problem with a JSONP calling,
i need to make several call to a javascript function

in the example the html page work only for the last function called not for all 3.

how i can resolve?

( the page work if i set a timeoutinterval, but i don't want that solution )

thanks

below the code

HTML PAGE

**

```
<!-- start codice che va aggiunto al box ADV -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/nativeadv/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/nativeadv/client_location/visualizzaJsonHome.js"></script>
<div class="contenutoHomeNativeAdv" id="contenutoHomeNativeAdvCirioHome"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">getAdv("CirioHome");</script>
<!-- end codice che va aggiunto al box ADV -->
<!-- end codice che va aggiunto al box ADV -->
<div class="contenutoHomeNativeAdv" id="contenutoHomeNativeAdvcoca1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">getAdv("coca1");
</script>
<div class="contenutoHomeNativeAdv" id="contenutoHomeNativeAdvkinder_client"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">getAdv("kinder_client");
```

**
The error is:

[image]
JS PAGE

```
function getAdv(nick){
    nick_cliente=nick;
    URLJSONP = LINK_BASE_URL+URL_JSONCB;
    $.ajax({
            url: URLJSONP,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp"
    });
}

function clAdv(json){
    var adv_stamp;
    ricercaAdv=json;
    dettAdv='';
    for(var i=0;i<ricercaAdv["adv"].length;i++){
        if(ricercaAdv["adv"][i].id==id_adv){
            dettAdv+='<div class="nativeadvtitlecontent" ><h1>'+ricercaAdv["adv"][i].Titolo+ '</h1></div>';
            dettAdv+='<div class="nativeadvdatacontent" >'+ricercaAdv["adv"][i].Datainserimento+ '</div>';          
        }
    }   
    document.getElementById("contenutoContentNativeAdv").innerHTML=dettAdv;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the values of `LINK_BASE_URL` and `URL_JSONCB`

Comment: The problem is about async, i resolve the issue using async : false